# Bash: How to extract table-like structures from text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a log file which contains some data and important table-like parts as following:

```
    //Some data

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----                 Output Table                             -----
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            NAME                         Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fooooooooo                               0        0          3        0        0
    boooooooooooooooooooooo                  0        0         30        0        0
    abv                                      0        0         16        0        0
    bhbhbhbh                                 0        0          3        0        0
    foooo                                    0        0        198        0        0

    WARNING: Some message...


    WARNING: Some message...

    aaaaaaaaa                                0        0         60        0        7
    bbbbbbbb                                 0        0         48        0        7
    ccccccc                                  0        0         45        0        7
    rrrrrrr                                  0        0         50        0        7
    abcabca                                  0        0         42        0        6

// Some data...

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----                 Another Output Table                                 -----
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         NAME                            Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $$foo12                                  0        0          3        0        0
    $$foo12_720_720_14_2                     0        0         30        0        0
```

I want to extract all that kind of tables from given file and save in separate files.

**Notes:**

- *A start of the table indicates a line which contains {NAME, Attr1, ..., Attr5} words*.
- *WARNING messages may exist in the scope of a table and should be ignored*.
- *Table ends when an empty line occurs and the next of that blank line is not a "WARNING" line.*

So I expect the following 2 files as output:

```
        NAME                         Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fooooooooo                               0        0          3        0        0
boooooooooooooooooooooo                  0        0         30        0        0
abv                                      0        0         16        0        0
bhbhbhbh                                 0        0          3        0        0
foooo                                    0        0        198        0        0
aaaaaaaaa                                0        0         60        0        7
bbbbbbbb                                 0        0         48        0        7
ccccccc                                  0        0         45        0        7
rrrrrrr                                  0        0         50        0        7
abcabca                                  0        0         42        0        6
```

---

```
     NAME                            Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$$foo12                                  0        0          3        0        0
$$foo12_720_720_14_2                     0        0         30        0        0
```

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42931008/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the following awk script by following your directions.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# start a table with a NAME line
/^ +NAME/ {
    titles = $0
    print
    next
}

# don't print if not in table
! titles {
    next
}

# blank line may mean end-of-table
/^$/ {
    EOT = 1
    next
}

# warning is not EOT
/^WARNING/ {
    EOT = 0
    next
}

# end of table means we're not in a table anymore, Toto
EOT {
    titles = 0
    EOT = 0
    next
}

# print what's in the table
{ print }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+' 'NF>6 || ($0 ~ /-/ && $0 !~ "Output") {print $0}' f
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            NAME                         Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fooooooooo                               0        0          3        0        0
    boooooooooooooooooooooo                  0        0         30        0        0
    abv                                      0        0         16        0        0
    bhbhbhbh                                 0        0          3        0        0
    foooo                                    0        0        198        0        0
    aaaaaaaaa                                0        0         60        0        7
    bbbbbbbb                                 0        0         48        0        7
    ccccccc                                  0        0         45        0        7
    rrrrrrr                                  0        0         50        0        7
    abcabca                                  0        0         42        0        6
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         NAME                            Attr1    Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $$foo12                                  0        0          3        0        0
    $$foo12_720_720_14_2                     0        0         30        0        0
```